# find the dimensions of the range of A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

$$
A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 & 1 & 3 & 0\\ 2 & -4 & 4 & 6 & 4\\ -2 & 4 & -1 & -6 & 2 \\ 1 &-2 & -3 & 3 & -8
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Im not sure how to approach this but i have some idea..

So i first tried to find the range of the matrix by doing row reduction to echelon form and i got the matrix below

$$
A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 & 0 & 3 & -2\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

when i identified the columns with pivots that are equal to 0. i got the range below

{(1,2,-2,1), (1,4,-1,-3)}

So how do i find the dimensions of the range? is the dimension just the number of vectors in the range? or is it the number of values in the vectors?

Comment: It is the rank of the echelon form of the matrix since row operations do not change the rank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dimension of the range is $2$, since the range is spanned by the columns. In the row reduced form there are only $2$ independent columns, those with leading ones. Note that relations between columns are the same in the reduced form as in the original. For example we see from the reduced form that the fourth column is three times the first column. The same holds in the original.

(Incidentally, we see this is false for the third and last column, meaning that the reduction given has some error in it.)

Comment: Yes you were right, there was an error in the reduction, i have corrected it. This might sound stupid but, i just want to make sure. so the number of dimensions of the range is 2 because of the number of vectors in the span of the range?

Comment: @Soon_to_be_code_master There are two pivoted columns in the row reduced echelon of your matrix. So there are two vectors in the in the basis of column space of your matrix. So the rank is 2.

Comment: Well it still aint correct, by exactly the same comment in my answer.

Comment: @A---B does the same logic apply for the kernel of a matrix? lets say the basis of a kernel has 3 vectors, does that mean that the kernel has 3 dimensions?

Comment: @Soon_to_be_code_master No, of course not. It is kernel polar opposite of  column space. To find kernel you need to solve $A\textbf x = \textbf b$, you will get $\textbf x = \textbf a + \sum \alpha_k \textbf c_k$, where $\alpha_k$ are the free variables of the solution. The set $\{ \textbf c_k \}$ is basis for the kernel. If you just want to know number of vectors in kernel, use rank-nullity theorem.